Is it possible to have async in a KVM with only one vCPU core?
I'm running a cheap VPS plan with only 1 vCPU core. My webapp's backend has asynchronous operations using python concurrent.futures. It works fine on my machine, but in the VPS, the async operation seems to not happen at all. The server still runs fine, and I'm not seeing any error logs.
I'm wondering if it's because of the 1vCPU, and maybe I need to upgrade my VPS plan.

That's unlikely to be your problem. You should add some more logging to your program or run it in an interactive debugger to see what's going on in your VPS machine.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52465317/can-i-run-multiprocessing-python-programs-on-a-single-core-machine
